# Change an image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a game of hangman where if someone guesses an incorrect letter it adds the image changes. to accomplish this I created a variable that when an incorrect letter is guessed is incremented and I use Jquery .html to change the picture. The problem I have is that the first wrong guess changes the picture but subsequent guesses do not. Is this because Jquery's .html just adds another div? what is a good solution to this? Below is the code

```
var word;
var wrongGuess = 0;
var usedLetters = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    SetGameBoard();
});

//When guess button is clicked
$('#BtnGuess').click(function () {
    CheckGuess();
});

function GetPhrase() {
    word = ReturnWord();
    alert(word);
}

function SetGameBoard() {
    $('#WinLose').hide();
    $('#controls').show();
    GetPhrase();
    wordToGuess = new Array(word.length);

     // Place underscore for each letter in the answer word in the DivWord div
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
       wordToGuess[i] = "_ ";
     }
    $('#DivWord').html(wordToGuess);
}


function CheckGuess() {
    var pos = 0;
    var posArray = [];
    var guessLetter = $('#tbGuessLetter').val();
    var picNum = 0;


    //check to see if letter has been used 
    if(usedLetters.indexOf(guessLetter) != -1){
        alert("You've already used this Letter!");
    }

    //populate array with indices of occurrences of guessed letter
    while ((pos = word.indexOf(guessLetter, pos)) > -1) {
        posArray.push(++pos);
        }

    //if the guessed letter is not in the word...
    if (posArray.length == 0) {
        picNum++;
        alert(guessLetter + " is not in the word.");
        $('#DivPic').html('<img src="images/h'+picNum+'.png" />');



    }else{
        //iterate over array of underscores (wordToGuess[]) and splice in guessed letter
      for(i=0; i < posArray.length; i++){
        wordToGuess.splice(posArray[i] - 1, 1, guessLetter);
       }
        //update DivWord
        $('#DivWord').html(wordToGuess);
        usedLetters.push(guessLetter);
    }
    $('#tbGuessLetter').val("");

}
```

Comment: could you add more code? the one before posArray

Comment: do you have a click event handler... if so how is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move **picNum** to the top, to declare it as global:

```
var picNum = 0;
var word;
var wrongGuess = 0;
var usedLetters = [];
```

Because each time it goes to the `CheckGuess()`  function it resets to zero, then if the user fails it will only increment to 1. That's why you are seeing the same image (first time)